# Delphi TRESTClient POST example --data vs. body

Tags: rest, delphi, jira-rest-api

I am trying to update Jira comments via the provided curl example in Jira's documentation, but I am always getting HTTP error code 415 or 400 for the different functions.

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31/comment

{
    "body": "This is a comment regarding the quality of the response."
}
```

```pascal
request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPost;
request.Params.AddItem('Content-Type','application/json',   TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
request.Resource := '/jira/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31/comment';
request.AddBody('{"This is a rest api comment update." }', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
request.Params.AddItem('body','{"This is a rest api comment update." }' , TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
request.Params.AddItem('data','{"body": "This." }',TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
request.Body.Add('{"body": "This is a rest api comment update." }', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
request.Execute;
```

What is the proper way to send the `--data`?

```
a) request.AddBody
b) request.Body.Add
c) request.Params.AddItem
```

BTW, query data with rmGet and PAT authentication is working fine.

Comment: Hello, you need to do a Authentication before. Did you read this doc? https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/

Comment: Hi Zeppi, yes, as mentioned , querying coment is working fine with PAT
jira/rest/api/2/issue/' + id + '/comment'

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Connect-to-JIRA-from-Delphi/qaq-p/2412505#M637583

only add comment is not working

Comment: Hello, in deed I not read the last sentence. So, in the documentation https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.4.0/#api/2/issue-addComment is wrote "error 400, Returned if the input is invalid (e.g. missing required fields, invalid values, and so forth)." could you try with copy paste exemple code `request.AddBody('{"body": "Lorem ip .... }')`

Comment: with addbody it's working fine.

body_s:= '{ "body": "This is a comment regarding the quality of the response."}';
              request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPost;
              request.Resource := '/jira/rest/api/2/issue/' + id + '/comment';
              request.AddBody(body_s, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
              request.Execute;

I had issue with memo1.text. there were some special chars at the end

Many thanks for quick help
Andreas

Comment: @awohlmut the "special characters" were probably just line breaks that would break the JSON syntax if you don't escape them. Try using `TJSONObject` to prepare your data.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for review and the hint to use TJSONObject , I will give a try